# How do we terminate screen sessions based on their attached or detached properties or their IDs?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, gnu-screen

### The problem:

We accidentally created close to 80 screens while running an experiment.

We could terminate them one by one using their IDs. But, is there a way to end them all using a script or a combination of commands to automate the process and save time doing so?

```
There are screens on:
    31408.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31396.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31384.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31372.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31360.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31348.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31336.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31324.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31312.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31300.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31288.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:14 PM)    (Attached)
    31276.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31264.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31252.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31240.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31228.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31216.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31204.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31192.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31180.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31168.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31156.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31144.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31132.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31120.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31108.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31096.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31084.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31072.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31060.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31048.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:13 PM)    (Attached)
    31036.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    31024.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    31012.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    31000.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30988.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30976.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30964.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30952.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30940.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30928.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30916.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30904.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30892.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30880.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30868.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30856.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30844.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30832.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30820.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30808.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30796.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:12 PM)    (Attached)
    30784.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30772.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30760.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30748.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30736.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30724.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30712.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30700.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30688.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30676.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30664.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30652.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30640.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30628.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30616.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30604.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30592.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30580.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30568.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30556.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30544.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30532.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30520.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30508.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:11 PM)    (Attached)
    30496.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Attached)
    30484.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Attached)
    30471.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Attached)
    30458.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Attached)
    30446.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Attached)
    30433.erpnext   (12/27/2019 03:13:10 PM)    (Detached)
    5061.erpnext    (12/23/2019 06:03:38 PM)    (Detached)
83 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-erpnext.
```

### What we want to do:

Terminate all but `5061.erpnext`.

### What we've tried so far:

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509677/kill-detached-screen-session)

```
#!/bin/bash
running_screens=$(screen -ls | grep -v "5061.erpnext")
echo "${running_screens}"

for i in {$running_screens}
do
    screens=$(${i} | grep ".")

    if [[ ${screens} != "" ]]; then
        echo "${i}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: There's a disconnect here between `grep -v erp1` and screen 5061.erpnext; is there a different username or session name?

Comment: Oops, copied the output for `screen -ls` from the server where the problem was. As for the disconnect, we ran `screen -dmS erp{1,2,3,4,6,7}` one command at a time on the client and then tried writing the bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard shell syntax:

```
cd /var/run/screen/S-erpnext
for screen in *
do
  case $screen in
    (5061.erpnext) : do nothing         ;;
    (*)            kill "${screen%%.*}" ;;
  esac
done
```

The above changes to the screen directory for that user then loops through every session file in that directory. If the session is *not* 5061.erpnext, then it kills the corresponding PID (the number before the first period). The `${screen%%.*}` expansion removes as many characters as possible from the end of the string until it finds a period. This has the effect of stripping off the stuff that is *not* the PID. The `: do nothing` uses the `:` built-in, which does nothing, which includes ignoring any parameters, so I made the line self-commenting, to indicate that we do *not* kill any PID for that case.